# ionic android does not parse $http json

Tags: php, android, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to get my ionic app running on Android and, viola, ran into this bug:

I am sending a request with :

```
    console.log(requestURL);
    $http.get(requestURL).success(function (results) {

        doCoolStuff(results);

    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('Error with request!');
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(headers);
    });
```

and by printing and checking requestURL I get a valid JSON object:

```
{"data":"9410230"}
```

that is sent by PHP though:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// echo $queryTide;
echo json_encode(array('data' => $mydata), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

It works perfectly fine as an standalone App in iOS and through `ionic serve` in Chrome, but with Android it ends up catching an error and logs:

```
5     684461   log      Error with request!
6     684462   log      
7     684463   log      0
8     684463   log
```

Do I need to more headers in PHP?

Comment: What is your `doCoolStuff(results)` actually doing? typically the data that you're after when using a `$http` is `.success(result){ doCoolStuff(result.data.value)}` Note that I passed `data.value`

Comment: Matt, doCoolStuff is a placeholder to focus the question on the fact that Android never gets into the success bracket...